# Installing .exe file using Powershell Script

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-ssm

I have tried to install .exe file on multiple machines hosted on AWS via System Manager. But it won't work. Can anyone please correct this script to installed on SSM.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "example.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents" /S  -PassThru
```

When i tried this script into the Server. I get installation prompt.
[image]

Comment: What executable is this? Does it support silent installation?

Comment: this is the 64 bit installer and also support silent installtion

Comment: 64 bit installer for what?

Comment: Yes its support Silent installation. I have tried this cmd in cmd prompt "msiexec /i "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Example.msi" /qr " in Cmd prompt this works properly.

Comment: So why don't you use the same switches in Powershell?

Comment: I works only inside the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried 'Start-Process -FilePath "example.exe" -ArgumentList "/S" -WindowStyle Hidden'

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But this also get the installation prompt screen

Comment: Do you have the msi package? Because in that case you can use: 'msiexec /i C:\temp\Example.msi /quiet' that work even in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Start-Process C:\New\Ccleaner.exe" -Argument "/Silent" -PassThru
```

[Source](https://linuxhint.com/exe-silent-installation-in-powershell/)